How to open popup in contentscripts.js?
I'm trying to make a chrome extension that is a translator and ALSO displays a contextual menu on text select.
Everything works fine, but one of my menu items is Translate, which I require to open a tooltip its onclick.
I think it's not possible to open the popup like the user clicked the extension icon, so if I'm right can I display the popup above the selected text like the following image?


This question is similar to: How can I open my extension's pop-up with JavaScript?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@realhuman I edited it. If it's not possible to show the popup like the user clicked it I want to show something like a popup. See image

I think you're describing a customized tooltip instead. In that case, would it be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853232/how-to-get-the-css-for-tooltip-which-appears-on-hover ? Note that you can inject HTML into sites with Javascript

@realhuman That is a tooltip but I don't want it to go away when you move your mouse away or click (because, someone may need to change the target language)

Ahh, perhaps this might help then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771561/how-to-make-tooltip-stay-visible-after-cursor-is-no-longer-hovering-it
